# High latency in updating the read database with HAProxy and Debezium

Tags: mysql, postgresql, apache-kafka-connect, haproxy, debezium

I have been trying to implement a Change Data Capture prototype for updating the read database in near-real time. I have used Debezium to stream changes in my source database (MySQL) to the sink database (PostgreSQL). The following is the project I have worked on for achieving the task.
https://github.com/AmanLonare/CDC-MySQL-Debezium-PostgreSQL

I am more interested in the latency in updating the read view once the operation is done on write side. The above project works fine and is pretty fast in updating the read database.

Now I have introduced one additional component, HAProxy, which is configured with my source database. My main objective is to have HAProxy to failover to stand by replica of MySQL in future. The following is the project link: https://github.com/AmanLonare/debezium-test

Now adding the HAProxy has greatly impacted my performance and it takes more than a minute sometimes to update my read database. It seems like Kafka Connect is periodically losing connection with MySQL and then trying to restore the connection. Also, the Kafka Broker is not available sometimes and there are times when I get "Node -1 disconnected" kind of error. The following are the logs. We can also enable TRACE level logs just by adding an environment variable to docker image of Kafka Connect with "LOG_LEVEL=TRACE". These are repeating logs which tend to repeat every few minutes.

Logs.txt

```
connect_1    | Aug 03, 2022 6:06:04 AM com.github.shyiko.mysql.binlog.BinaryLogClient$5 run

connect_1    | INFO: Trying to restore lost connection to mysql:3306

connect_1    | 2022-08-03 06:06:04,271 INFO   MySQL|dbserver1|binlog  Creating thread debezium-mysqlconnector-dbserver1-binlog-client   [io.debezium.util.Threads]

mysql_1      | 2022-08-03T06:06:04+00:00 ba3189cef8ad haproxy[14]: Connect from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:55506 to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:3306 (haproxy/TCP)

connect_1    | Aug 03, 2022 6:06:04 AM com.github.shyiko.mysql.binlog.BinaryLogClient connect

connect_1    | INFO: Connected to mysql:3306 at mysql-bin.000003/492 (sid:184054, cid:90)

kafka_1      | 2022-08-03 06:07:05,810 - DEBUG [main-SendThread(zookeeper:2181):ClientCnxn$SendThread@890] - Got ping response for session id: 0x100029960670000 after 0ms.

kafka_1      | 2022-08-03 06:07:08,385 - DEBUG [data-plane-kafka-network-thread-1-ListenerName(PLAINTEXT)-PLAINTEXT-0:Selector@606] - [SocketServer listenerType=ZK_BROKER, nodeId=1] Connection with /xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx (channelId=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:9092-xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:57476-38) disconnectedkafka_1      | java.io.EOFException

connect_1    | 2022-08-03 06:07:08,385 INFO   ||  [Consumer clientId=consumer-1-1, groupId=1] Node 2147483646 disconnected.   [org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient]

connect_1    | 2022-08-03 06:07:08,386 INFO   ||  [Consumer clientId=consumer-1-1, groupId=1] Group coordinator xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:9092 (id: 2147483646 rack: null) is unavailable or invalid due to cause: coordinator unavailable.isDisconnected: true. Rediscovery will be attempted.   [org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator]

connect_1    | 2022-08-03 06:07:08,387 INFO   ||  [Consumer clientId=consumer-1-1, groupId=1] Discovered group coordinator xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:9092 (id: 2147483646 rack: null)   [org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator]

connect_1    | 2022-08-03 06:07:08,387 INFO   ||  [Consumer clientId=consumer-1-1, groupId=1] Group coordinator xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:9092 (id: 2147483646 rack: null) is unavailable or invalid due to cause: coordinator unavailable.isDisconnected: false. Rediscovery will be attempted.   [org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator]

connect_1    | 2022-08-03 06:07:08,387 INFO   ||  [Consumer clientId=consumer-1-1, groupId=1] Requesting disconnect from last known coordinator xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:9092 (id: 2147483646 rack: null)   [org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator]

connect_1    | 2022-08-03 06:07:08,488 INFO   ||  [Consumer clientId=consumer-1-1, groupId=1] Discovered group coordinator xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:9092 (id: 2147483646 rack: null)   [org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator]

connect_1    | 2022-08-03 06:07:09,047 INFO   ||  [Consumer clientId=consumer-1-3, groupId=1] Node 2147483646 disconnected.   [org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient]

connect_1    | 2022-08-03 06:07:09,048 INFO   ||  [Consumer clientId=consumer-1-3, groupId=1] Group coordinator xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:9092 (id: 2147483646 rack: null) is unavailable or invalid due to cause: coordinator unavailable.isDisconnected: true. Rediscovery will be attempted.   [org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator]

kafka_1      | 2022-08-03 06:07:09,047 - DEBUG [data-plane-kafka-network-thread-1-ListenerName(PLAINTEXT)-PLAINTEXT-2:Selector@606] - [SocketServer listenerType=ZK_BROKER, nodeId=1] Connection with /xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx (channelId=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:9092-xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:57478-38) disconnectedkafka_1      | java.io.EOFException
```

Comment: Is the network flaky?  Please provide the specific query that it is taking "too long".

Comment: The time taken to update the sink database which is PostgreSQL in this case is too long. I have two terminals open, one for updating the "customers" table of the "inventory" database inside the MySQL container. The other terminal executing the PostgreSQL database where I query the status of "customers" table (once both source and sink connectors are registered, the data is successfully replicated from MySQL database to PostgreSQL). In the first terminal (MySQL), I "INSERT" a data into  customers table and immediately monitor for change in second terminal (PostgreSQL).

Comment: The time taken to see the change in the PostgreSQL is around 90 seconds. However, of I do the same test with the setup where I do not have HAProxy configured, then it is quite immediate. I am not sure if it is the network problem because it works fine in case of the setup where I don't have HAProxy configured.

Comment: So, this is a Postgres + HAProxy issue, not MySQL??  (Fix tags?)

Comment: I am not sure if the issue is related to MySQL or not because the connection of Kafka Connect with MySQL is lost frequently and connect takes few seconds to restore the connection back with MySQL. I have fixed the tags with more related topics.

Comment: Look for "timeout" settings in all the component products.

Comment: @AmanLonare any news? I'm currently facing the same issue but I can't get rid of those logs...

Comment: @c.bear
I did not find any solution for this. I have substituted HAProxy with ProxySQL and it seems to be working fine for me now with immediate update of the sink database  (PostgreSQL).